# How to insert map type into cassandra using cassandra-driver for python

Tags: python, cassandra

Since, cassandra supports map type. I want to insert a python dict into cassandra. I tried this:

```
cql = "Insert into table_name (my_key, name, my_dict) values (%s, %s, %s)" % (my_key, name, my_dict)

session.execute(cql)
```

This obviously didn't work.

I already have a map type column in my column family.
How do I go about it?

Error:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [parameter passing form](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.21/getting_started/#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries) instead of string interpolation:

```
cql = "Insert into table_name (my_key, name, my_dict) values (%s, %s, %s)"
session.execute(cql,  (my_key, name, my_dict))
```

Comment: Same error:"not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: @extraDarker, Could you update your question with the error message (full traceback if possible).

Comment: I take my comment back, Worked!